# How to get an image srcset inside page.html.twig in Drupal 8?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I've figured out how to get the image link:

```
{{ node.myfieldname.entity.uri.value }}
```

I've been poking around with kint for a bit now, but can't figure out if there is a srcset anywhere.

When loading the image normally through `{{ content }}` it does display a srcset, so it should have one. Just not sure if it is already available on the page.html.twig or where to find it.

The actual goal is to retreive the image srcset to use the image as a background. I'm trying to retreive multiple images to use as backgrounds for multiple div's that are defined in my page--front.html.twig

Comment: Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a custom block for my image, that only shows the image.
Then added the custom block to my page.html.twig

Not the prettiest solution, but easy and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Getting access to all the node information at the page template level generally means large and painful selectors and extra rendering. It's generally easier to create a [helper function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194176/loading-default-image-from-a-node-field-in-page-html-twig) and hook within your theme file to make the values easier to access.

Depending on the details of your use case the [Background Image Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter) may do what you need without much custom code.

If that approach doesn't work for you consider a [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x) to find and extract the values you want from the field. You can move them into simple to use variables for the template.

Comment: Was trying this, but the srcset value is not present in the page or node, not in twig nor in the preprocess hooks. I did only try preprocess_page, not proprocess_node.